# How to get the numbers of variables in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to select some variables (f,g,h) from my large dataframe
for example [,7:9], but first I have to look and tediously count them

```
> names(dataframe)
[1] a b c d
[5] e f g h 
[9] i j k l
...
```

how do I get?

```
[1] a [2] b [3] c [4] d [5] e ...
```

Comment: Why is it needed?  If you need to get the numbers in each line `op <- options(width = 10); names(dataframe)`  and reset it afterwards

Comment: If this is subsetting issue, then you can directly use the column name i.e. `dataframe[c('f', 'g', 'h')]` instead of index

Comment: Thanks. I need it, because I know the names of the variables but I dont know their positions in the dataframe. So I need a way to display the positions of every single variable to be able to select variables that I need for correlations.

Comment: You can get the position by `match(c('f', 'g', 'h'), names(dataframe))` instead of checking the position one by one.  Also if you need it in a string format `sprintf("[%d] %s", seq_along(dataframe), names(dataframe))` or print it `cat(sprintf("[%d] %s", seq_along(dataframe), names(dataframe)), "\n")`

Comment: this works very well, thank you.

Comment: "So I need a way to display the positions of every single variable to be able to select variables that I need for correlations." That doesn't make sense. R supports subsetting by column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the index.  One option is `match`

```
match(c('f', 'g', 'h'), names(dataframe))
#[1] 6 7 8
```

If we need it to be printed in a specific way on the screen use `cat`

```
cat(sprintf("[%d] %s", seq_along(dataframe), names(dataframe)), "\n")
#[1] a [2] b [3] c [4] d [5] e [6] f [7] g [8] h [9] i [10] j [11] k [12] l
```